# Folder is not accessible to Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, access-control

I created a simple Windows Service as a test.  All the service does is create a text file on the local drive.  This emerged because the my production service was unable to drop a file in a new share that had been established, however I am not able to get this to work in my local workstation.

```
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            logger.Warn(string.Format("Specified folder {0} does not exist.", dropFolder));
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                sw.Write(fileContent);
                logger.Debug(string.Format("File {0} has been written.", filePath));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error("Unable to write the file " + filePath, ex);
    }
```

The service is not able to see the folder, even though it exists.  I've changed the Login of the service to an account that is a local admin and set the permissions on the folder to full control for that user.

Is there something special that is required when the user is logged on as a service?

Comment: Need more information.  Are you on a domain?  What's the share location?  Also, you need to authenticate as a user that the share host knows about, not a local user.

Comment: There is nothing unusual about writing files from services.  What is the path to the folder?  Try opening a command line in local system context using `psexec -s \\127.0.0.1 cmd` (if you don't already have psexec, you can download it from Microsoft's web site) and see whether it can see the folder in question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The server in question is on a domain, the user is a domain account and the share is share is located on another server on the same domain - \\Server02\DropFiles.
When I encountered the problem, I moved everything to the local server (Server01), and attempted to drop the file into a folder on Server01.  The domain user account was made a member of the local administrators on Server01.  The call to Directory.Exists returned false.